# Develop Windows like Replaceable Tiles using AngularJS 1.4?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, dashboard

How to develop windows like tiles ( replaceable ) in my dashboard ? 
the position of tiles can be changed and it other tiles should fit accordingly .

Answer (score 1):

The building blocks for these types of masonry is css [FlexBox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Try and understand the basics. It is great to know and solves a lot of problems with grid and responsive design.

This is in `jQuery` but I found `jQuery` in `AngularJs` is less confusing to use than in `Angular2` (Personal experience). This would answer your question specifically.

[**Create An Interactive Metro Style Grid Dashboard**](https://paulund.co.uk/create-interactive-grid-dashboard)

This should do the trick.

There is also [AngularJs Masonry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-masonry) npm package that you can look at. The css will most probably have to be done by you.

Comment: why should you use jQuery in an AngularJS or Angular project?

Comment: Mostly, there are not always an npm packages that one can download give you the functionality or feature required. If there is a angular metro package then we don't need jQuery I guess.